# how to link javascript and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

I have created a VERY simple program on a VERY simple html file.  I wish to simply find out how to link javascript to html and css.  Here follows my example code:

(index.html)

```
<head>
    <title>JavaScript</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="picture">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRZAb6KcZrNTBM1UflIMAQfAGuTKN0XWYFsiTgm5M5NRwXO_udT"/>
    </div>

    <button class="show_btn">Show</button>
    <button class="hide_btn">Hide</button>

    <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(".hide_btn").click(function(){ 
    $("p").slideUp(); 
  }); 
  $(".show_btn").click(function(){ 
    $("p").slideDown(); 
  }); 
});
```

CSS:

```
 .picture { display: none; }
```

Now with this code, I am attempting to use two buttons to show and hide a picture of a fish...I can't seem to get it to work however, and I believe it has something to do with how I am linking my files. Please Help!

Comment: my css looks like this:   .picture {
                                    display: none;
                                      }

Comment: and my javascript looks like this:   $(document).ready(function(){
$(".hide_btn").click(function(){
        $("p").slideUp();
    });
$(".show_btn").click(function(){
        $("p").slideDown();
    });
});

Comment: can you add your javascript to the question and not the comment? Ans also you are using jquery but you dont have jquery added to your document.

Comment: Added the code from comment

Comment: added CSS from comment

Answer (score 1):

Based off of your comment in your question it would appear that you are using jQuery but you do not have jQuery as part of your source code.

You will need to include the jQuery source above script.js.

Here is an example of how it should look like using Google CDN for the jQuery library:

```html
<head>
    <title>JavaScript</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="picture">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRZAb6KcZrNTBM1UflIMAQfAGuTKN0XWYFsiTgm5M5NRwXO_udT"/>
    </div>

    <button class="show_btn">Show</button>
    <button class="hide_btn">Hide</button>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this in javascript

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="picture" id="picture">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRZAb6KcZrNTBM1UflIMAQfAGuTKN0XWYFsiTgm5M5NRwXO_udT" />
  </div>
  <button class="show_btn" onclick="show();">Show</button>
  <button class="hide_btn" onclick="hide();">Hide</button>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function show(){
    var imgdiv = document.getElementById("picture");
    imgdiv.style.display="block";
}
function hide(){
    var imgdiv = document.getElementById("picture");
    imgdiv.style.display="none";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery you also need to link the jquery source above your .js link,

here is the google cdn (so you dont have to download it):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely use jQuery for something like this.  Here's a Plunker that shows how you can accomplish this.

http://embed.plnkr.co/DwTwNuF162rfgcQOdT7u/preview

```
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="picture" id="picture">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRZAb6KcZrNTBM1UflIMAQfAGuTKN0XWYFsiTgm5M5NRwXO_udT" />
  </div>
  <button class="show_btn" onclick="show()">Show</button>
  <button class="hide_btn" onclick="hide()">Hide</button>

</body>

<script>
  function show() {
    $('#picture').show();
  }

  function hide() {
    $('#picture').hide();
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first:

Include this in your `<head>`:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you're on Chrome try using the developer tools; right click on the page then inspect element. On the developer tools pane, select the CONSOLE tab which logs all your errors in your javascript

And try this in your script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".show_btn").click(function() {
    $(".picture").css('display', 'block');
  });
  $(".hide_btn").click(function() {
    $(".picture").css('display', 'none');
  });
});
```

Also I've noticed that you have div.picture display set to "none".

Answer (score 0):

All that you need to do is the following

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You can write javascript inside the script tags. (if you want to add javascript in HTML

the following is to link it to another file.

```
<script src="path to other file" > </script>
```

Comment: Forgot to add... it is different for jquery